# Why is a StackPanel behaving as if its Height was set to Auto when its Height is set from code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, stackpanel

I have the following code to make a StackPanel's height be 1.4 times its width.

C#:

```
private void AutoRun()
{
    //Page height
    double PageHeight = Window_1_Document_Page_1.Width * 1.4;
    Window_1_Document_Page_1.Height = PageHeight;
}
```

XAML:

```
<StackPanel Name="Window_1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">

    <Grid BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Black">
        <TextBlock FontSize="18" Name="Window_1_Title" Padding="5">New Document 1</TextBlock>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="Window_1_Close" Content="Close Window" Visibility="Collapsed" Click="CloseWindow_Click"/>
    </Grid>

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <Grid Name="Window_1_Document_Page_1" Margin="20" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Padding="10">
            <TextBox Name="TextBox1" AcceptsReturn="False" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="16" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ElementName = Window_1_Document_Page_1, Path = ActualWidth}" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>

</StackPanel>
```

However, the StackPanel `Window_1_Document_Page_1` renders as if its Height was set to `Auto`.

May someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: try to change inner StackPanel to Grid with 2 rows. where first row height = auto, second row height = *

Answer (score 0):

The property to get the width is called `ActualWidth` not `Width`, try this:

```
double PageHeight = Window_1_Document_Page_1.ActualWidth* 1.4;
Window_1_Document_Page_1.Height = PageHeight;
```